# Drive belt - the 5 years after manufacture date rule

Tags: timing-belt, rubber

Bought one drive belt 1.5 years ago for installing these days. My mechanic says not to use it if it is 5 years old rubber or older. No date stamp on the belt, also I was unable to find its manufacture date.

Is there any test I can do on it so to establish if it is still worthy before throwing it away ?

Comment: Are you talking about a cam belt, or are you talking about a serpentine belt (for the alternator, power steering pump, AC compressor, etc)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It is a timing belt, a.k.a cam belt

Comment: Do you want to be cheap and take the risk that it's degraded and might break prematurely or do you want to spend a few bucks for a new one?  If the vehicle is high-mileage I'd probably go cheap.